# Can we apply rules while creating user in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

I am creating user using sitecore membership provider. 
Can we apply rules while creating user in sitecore. If we can do that how to apply rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't supplied any specifics on the actual rules so I'll give you a generic answer. Sitecore's rules engine is made up of conditions and actions. You can create your own conditions and actions or use the existing set. For example sitecore comes with conditional rendering conditions for personalisation - you could say if a user is from a particular country show a different rendering. More info here

http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2013/09/The-Sitecore-DMS-Rules-Engine-3-cool-ways-to-use-it.aspx

It sounds like you may need to create your own conditions and actions, there is a good post here on how to do this, in this instance based on the querystring

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/custom-rules-and-conditions-for-sitecore-personalization/

This post also shows you how to create a custom action

https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/03/implement-a-rule-action-to-remove-an-insert-option-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

You can hook into the rules engine on the Item Saved and Deleted event by adding a new item of template /sitecore/templates/System/Rules/Rule under the item /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved/Rules and /sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Deleted/Rules

The rule item will have a Rule field where you can add your rules logic. You can use the conditions here that relate to a user. See screen shot.

[image]

Comment: thank you,how to use Item Saved or Item Deleted in rules.can we apply particular rule for Item Template.

Comment: See the update to the post. Don't forget to mark as answer if answered. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply.can you tell how to run the rule and how it works.I am new to sitecore please help me to fix this.

Comment: If you need to run rules on the item saved and deleted events then create the rules under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Item Saved` and `Item Deleted`. You can find more info on how to create the rules in https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2013/11/limiting-conditions-and-actions-with-sitecore-71.aspx